# VBA: Extract cells(1,1) from a saved xls file in Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

Note: I wrote the following code in Outlook VBA. Basically the code is in ThisOutlookSession and I scan emails that start with "new", save the attachment in Desktop and debug.print the value in Cells(1,1). However, Outlook crashed and said "Object doesn't support this property or method" on the "     Debug.Print sourceSH.Cells(1,1)" line. What is wrong?

```
Public WithEvents myOlItems  As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim f As Folder
    Set f = Application.Session.Folders.item("me").Folders.item("Inbox")

    Set myOlItems = f.Items

    Call LoadForm


End Sub

Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

  Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem

    Dim name As String
    Dim res As String

    Dim sourceWB As Workbook
    Dim sourceSH As Worksheet

    Dim NewFileName As String

    Dim xlApp As Object


    If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
        Set Msg = item


        ' do stuff with item
        If Left(Msg.Subject, 3) = "New" And Msg.Attachments.Count > 0 Then

            NewFileName = "C:\Desktop\" & Msg.Attachments.item(1).Filename

            ' save file
            Msg.Attachments.item(1).SaveAsFile NewFileName

            Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

            xlApp.Application.Visible = True

            Set sourceWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(NewFileName, True, True)

            Set sourceSH = sourceWB.Worksheets(1)

            Debug.Print sourceSH.Cells(1,1)

        End If

    End If

ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Try changing `Debug.Print sourceSH.Cells(1,1)` to `Debug.Print sourceSH.Cells(1,1).Value`

Comment: `.Value` is the default property of a range object, so it should not matter whether you do the `.Value` or not, but I suppose it is worth a try, or you could similarly try: `sourceSh.Range("A1").Value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Debug.Print sourceSH.Cells(1,1)

The Print method output the message to the immediate window. You need to pass a string, not the Range object. Try to pass the [Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840217(v=office.15).aspx) property values to the Print method.

```
Debug.Print sourceSH.Cells(1,1).Text
```